# Bootstrap popover arrow position

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

The bootstrap popover arrow is sometimes losing its position (center of the div which the popover is connected to) when popovers content stretches it's size. 
I've found that it's being fixed with replaceArrow method from the tooltip.js script.
The problem is that the arrow selector is not catching the arrow which has only the .arrow class (not .tooltip-arrow)

Though I can fix the behavior with custom markup for the popover, I would like to ask is this a bug in bootstrap or am I overlooking something?

I would like to avoid custom markup for popovers and customizing bootstrap script as it will be hard to maintain in the future.

```
arrow: function(){
   return this.$arrow = this.$arrow || this.tip().find(".tooltip-arrow")
   }
```

Comment: If I were you I would handle it this way: Create a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example of this happening so that you can confirm that it is a problem with bootstrap and not with the CSS within your site. If you can replicate the problem, open an issue here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues Be sure to include a link to the fiddle.js and they should be able to address it and let you know if it is something that can be fixed or not.

Answer (score -1):

You could give this a try. I have a similar situation where I remove the arrow from the tooltip.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".yourCssClassHere").tooltip().on("mouseenter", function () {
        var $this = $(this),
        tooltip = $this.next(".tooltip");

        tooltip.find(".tooltip-arrow").css({
            display: "none"
        });
    });
});
```